# How to show the progress bar that's hiding behind a modal dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

From a modal dialog I am opening another modal dialog box. And on clicking of a Submit button , I want to show a progress bar.

```
     $scope.case.submit = function () {

         //Show the processing progress bar
         myApp.showPleaseWait();

         var postParams = {

             "CreateCaseInput": {
                 "case_nm": $scope.case.name,
                  ....................
```

The Progress bar code looks like ...

```
var myApp;
myApp = myApp || (function () {

    var pleaseWaitDiv = $('<div class="modal fade" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h3>Processing...</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100%;"><span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');

    return {
        showPleaseWait: function () {
            pleaseWaitDiv.modal('show');
        },
        hidePleaseWait: function () {
            pleaseWaitDiv.modal('hide');
        },
    };
})();
```

But this bar is hiding behind the modal. What can be done ?

Comment: Increase `z-index` of your `progress` class in `CSS`. Set it to greater that `1500`

Comment: Just a suggestion but you could also look at [ngProgress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/) which might be either a substitution or a possible source of inspiration.